# Funds transfer authorization

Tags: c#, e-commerce

I have the working code but it is pretty dirty. The goal is to input a number  in an application. If it satisfies the min/max logic then jump to the authorization part. Afterwards we can confirm it or reenter it or cancel it. If fails then re-input it. So totally we can only input twice.

```
 public virtual CallerAuthorization GetCallerAuthorizationResult(decimal debitBalance)
    {
        bool success;
        try
        {
            _debitBalanceAmount = debitBalance;
            GetFundAmountToTransfer();
            success = BuildAmountMinMaxLogicLoop();
        }
        catch (HangupException)
        {
            throw new CallHangupException();
        }
        if (!success)
        {
            success = ReenterAmount();
        }
        if (!success)
            return null;
        AuthorizeTransfer();
        var result = GetProceedInstruction();
        if (result == "1")
            return _callerAuthorization;
        if (result == "2")
        {
            success = ReenterAmount();
            if (!success)
            {
                CancelAuthorization();
                return null;
            }
            AuthorizeTransferReenterAmount();
            return _callerAuthorization;
        }
        if (result == "3")
        {
            CancelAuthorization();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The other methods:

```
 public virtual bool BuildAmountMinMaxLogicLoop()
    {
        var isContainingSpecialChars = CheckWhetherInputContainingSpecialChars();
        var isNotAuthorizable = IsNotAuthorizable();
        if (isNotAuthorizable)
        {
            if (isContainingSpecialChars)
            {
                PlayTransferAmountLogicError();
                return false;
            }
            PlayTransferAmountLogicError();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Also:

```
public virtual bool ReenterAmount()
    {
        PlayFundAmountToTransferPrompt();
        GetFundAmountToTransfer();
        var isNotAuthorizable = IsNotAuthorizable();
        if (isNotAuthorizable)
        {
            PlayGoodByeMessagePrompt();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void AuthorizeTransferReenterAmount()
    {
        GetAuthorizationResult();
        if (ResultInfo.Code == 0 && AuthorizationInfo.ResultInfo.Code == 0)
        {
            _callerAuthorization.AuthCode = AuthCode;
            _callerAuthorization.FundsTransferInfo = FundsTransferInfo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some of the methods are missing. It would help if you can post the missing code.

Answer (score 1):

```
_debitBalanceAmount = debitBalance;
```

Assigning this to a member value doesn't seem right, and this is before any validation.

```
GetFundAmountToTransfer();
```

This function is implies it will return something, but you don't assign it anywhere.  This is a code smell.

```
var result = GetProceedInstruction();
if (result == "1")
    return _callerAuthorization;
```

A meaningless string literal, not good.  Make it an `enum` with a good name.  Where did `_callerAuthorization` get assigned?

The control flow is not complicated and yet it's hard to read.  Try breaking it up into smaller functions.